# Open downloaded files using default option in windows mobile app phonegap?

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating an windows8.1 mobile app in which i have a file download option. 
I am able to download file in my application. Know what i want after file download is complete it should show option to open file or directly open the file.
here is code i am trying :

```
function downloadFile(){

var folderPath = 'batMedia/'+downloadArr[0].filename;
var fileURL = rootObj.toURL()+folderPath;
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(downloadArr[0].path);
    console.log("downloading file is called");
    fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            fileURL,
            function(entry) {

               var storagePath = entry.fullPath;
              core.displayAlert("successfully download");
              console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>"+storagePath)
               insertNewsMedia(folderPath);
            },
            function(error) {

                  var msg = '';

                  switch (error.code) {
                    case 1:
                      msg = 'FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR';

                      break;
                    case 2:
                      msg = 'INVALID_URL_ERR';

                      break;
                    case 3:
                      msg = 'CONNECTION_ERR';
                      break;
                    case 4:
                      msg = 'ABORT_ERR';

                      break;
                    case 5:
                      msg = 'NOT_MODIFIED_ERR';

                      break;
                    default:
                      msg = 'Unknown Error';

                      break;
                  }

                  console.log(msg)
            }

    );}
```

Above is the code to download file. O tried to search but didnt found any example to open a file with default option in windows app.
cordova version is 3.8.1.

Any ideal is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Comment: hey @Aravin thanks for reply I tried to use file-opener2 plugin but how to get the absolute path of the downloaded file...